# Induction Proof clarifications, and how to define abstract relations

Tags: induction, relations

I am completely  at a loss as to how to even start Exercise 4, as well as formally defining the two relations in 5. For Exercise 4, I can't figure out what to compare 2^(n-1) to. I mean, there has to be some equality expression somewhere in order to prove something by induction, right? Or am I completely mistaken there? Finally, I already solved whether or not the relations in 5 are equivalence relations, so I'm fine on that front.

I don't want the problems to be solved, just a hint or a clarifying point, or something along those lines.

Edit: I figured 3 out, I was just messing up the induction, as one of the comments pointed out.

[image: Questions I am confused about]

Comment: For 4 : base case $n=1$. How many cases we have to split $1$ with positive integers ? Only one. And $2^{n-1}=2^0=1$.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should've specified that I knew the base case, sorry about that. I have worked out a few numbers already (up to 4), but I can't seem to figure out a pattern. Also, how does the base case help? It only proves that the original statement holds.

Comment: Then assume that the property holds for $n$, i.e. that $n$ has $2^{n-1}$ splittings  and prove that $n+1$ has $2^n= 2(2^{2-1})$ splittings.

Comment: You write: "I understand how induction works", but the things you've written on your paper, from about the middle of the sheet down, indicate otherwise. For instance, the very first thing you "assume" is the thing you're trying to prove. That's a bad start.

Comment: yeah, I figured. I reworked it after seeing this, and I got it

Comment: For Exercise 5i we have $(0,0,0)\approx (0,1,1)$ and $(0,1,1)\approx (1,1,1)$ but $(0,0,0)\not \approx (1,1,1).$... A computer theorist would say that if a bit-string $A$ was sent but received as $B$ with $2$ errors, and $B$ was sent but received as $C$ with a $3$rd error then $A\approx B$ and $B\approx C$ but $A\not \approx C.$

Comment: For Exercise 5ii, which  $(a,b)$ satisfy $(a,b)\sim (0,0)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Exercise 3 let $P(n)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1-2^{-j})$ for $n\in \Bbb N.$ If $P(n)\geq  2^{-2}+2^{-n-1}$ then $$P(n+1)-(2^{-2}+2^{-n-2})=$$ $$=(1-2^{-n-1})P(n)-(2^{-2}+2^{-n-2})\geq$$ $$\geq (1-2^{-n-1})(2^{-2}+2^{-n-1})-(2^{-2}+2^{-n-2})=$$ $$=(2^{-2}+2^{-n-1}-2^{-n-3}-2^{-2n-2})-(2^{-2}+2^{-n-2})=$$ $$=((2^{-n-1}-2^{-n-2})-2^{-n-3})-2^{-2n-2}=$$ $$=(2^{-n-2}-2^{-n-3})-2^{-2n-2}=$$ $$=2^{-n-3}-2^{-2n-2}=$$ $$=2^{-2n-2}(2^{n-1}-1)\geq 0.$$

Comment: thanks! I did it a bit differently, but ended up with the same thing! good sign

Comment: The general idea is to express $P(n+1)$ as some formula $P(n+1)=f(P(n))$  to see how information about $P(n)$ affects $f(P(n)).$

Comment: for 5ii, if you leave the formula as is, (a,b) can be any integer. However, if you solve for either a or b, you get (0*a,b)/0, which is indeterminate. Because of this, do I have to exclude (0,0) from Z x Z?

Comment: (I). In 5ii you cannot  solve $a0=b0=0$ for $a$ or $b$ in the sense that you cannot find any $a$ or $b$ in $\Bbb Z$ that does NOT satisfy it.... (II). We have $(1,2)\sim (0,0)$ and $(0,0)\sim(3,4)$ but do we have $(1,2)\sim (3,4)$?... The Q is about $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$. If you change that then you have a different Q. Different Q's can also be interesting, except on exams and homework.

Comment: but then to define it, isn't it just { (a,b) ~ (a',b') [is in] Z x Z | ab' = a'b }? I feel like that's almost too simple

Comment: that, and it doesn't actually clarify anything about the relation itself.